# Could you explain how Google bot's visit frequency is determined?

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, bots

Dear fellow developers,

I am operating a website for my small research items.
I found one weird thing regarding my website, nowadays, and would like to ask a question.
Although my website has never been updated often (probably, once or twice a month), Google bots visited my website almost 10 ~ 20 times everyday.
So, my website has almost nothing to crawl and index, the bots kept visiting my website.
Is there anyone who can tell me why?
How is the frequency of the bots' visits determined?
I am well aware of the fact that Google did not expose the technical details of the crawlers but any wild guess will be welcomed.
Thank you for your answer, in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.